# Codeigniter set email from in config

Tags: codeigniter, email

I was wondering if it would be able to define the `from` and `reply_to` of a CI email in the config of the email like the following:

```
$mail_config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => $school_custom['smtp_host'],
    'smtp_port' => $school_custom['smtp_port'],
    'smtp_user' => $school_custom['smtp_user'],
    'smtp_pass' => $school_custom['smtp_password'],
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'from' => 'from_email',
    'reply_to' => 'reply_to_email'
);

$this -> load -> library('email', $mail_config);
```

The reason I am looking for this is because the place where I load my library is at the top of my function and where is set the from and reply_to are at the bottom, so I want to group these together with the config, because they will be the same for all emails that will be sent.

I could not find anything about this and the tests I tried on the above does not seem to work, so I am not completely sure that it is possible.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create file `APPPATH.'config/custom_email.php'`:

```
<?php
$config = [
    'from_mail' => 'from@mail.com',
    'reply_to_email' => 'reply_to@email.com',
];
```

Autoload file within `APPPATH.'config/custom_mail.php'`:

```
$autoload['config'] = array('custom_email');// line 106
```

Use it this way:

```
$mail_config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => $school_custom['smtp_host'],
    'smtp_port' => $school_custom['smtp_port'],
    'smtp_user' => $school_custom['smtp_user'],
    'smtp_pass' => $school_custom['smtp_password'],
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'from' => $this->config->item('from_mail'),
    'reply_to' => $this->config->item('reply_to_email')
);

$this -> load -> library('email', $mail_config);
```

Also you can set other values as per your need in that or some other config file.
If that configuration is all time static configuration, you can pass all values in config file and load it directly with one line of code following [manual loading](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html#manual-loading) as described in docs.